# i3wm has wrong scaling when running on Ubuntu virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox, display, display-resolution, i3-wm

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.2 on a VirtualBox virtual machine. I want to use i3 window manager with it, and have installed it as such.

One problem I came across was that, even with guest additions installed, the guest was not detecting the correct screen resolution, so I set up an `.xprofile` file with the necessary commands to set the resolution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
 
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode Virtual1 1920x1080_60.00
xrandr -s 1920x1080_60.00
```

The problem with this is that `.xprofile` is run quite late into the login sequence, presumably after i3 has started, since it ends up looking like this:

[image: Resolution problem]

Clearly, the status bar and top title bar are using the old dpi, and display way too large as a result.

So, what can I do to resolve this? Is there a better method of obtaining a 1920x1080 resolution that i3 will respect? Are there any i3 settings I can edit to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by adding a custom xorg configuration at`/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/5-monitor.conf`, with the contents:

```
Section "Monitor"
   Identifier "HD Monitor"
   Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
EndSection
Section "Device"
   Identifier "Configured device"
EndSection
Section "Screen"
   Identifier "Default screen"
   Device "Configured device"
   Monitor "HD Monitor"
   DefaultDepth 24
   SubSection "Display"
      Depth 24
      Modes "1920x1080_60.00"
   EndSubSection
EndSection
```

This configuration is loaded early enough in the login process to affect the way that i3 is set up.

Comment: So it's a static resolution 1920x1080, right? Do you know how to do a dynamic resolution when you resize a window with a VM? Dynamic resolution works with Ubuntu live CD, but not with my i3 inside a VM.